# learning node express, why console does not output 'localhost'?

Tags: node.js, express

I am learning to use express and node in general and I realise that I could be missing many fundamental knowledge. Below is the code for starting a server to serve static files, and as i understand the console should output the server address and port number on startup.

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static('resources'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname));

app.get('/', function (req, res) {
   res.sendFile( __dirname + "/" + "index.html" );
})

var server = app.listen(3000, function () {

  var host = server.address().address
  var port = server.address().port

  console.log("Server listening at http://%s:%s", host, port)

})
```

I am expecting to see 'Server listening at http://localhost:3000"' but instead i get: '**Server listening at http://:::3000**'

Can anyone explain what this means please
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the documentation on [`net.Server::address()`](https://nodejs.org/api/net.html#net_server_address).

It probably doesn't say `localhost` because you didn't specify what address you were listening for.

By default, there is no specific address because it will accept incoming requests on the port regardless of the address it was sent to.

Examples of various addresses it could accept are `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, `192.168.1.72` or if you port-forward your server through your network, it could be your global IP address. If you explicitly specify an address, it will reject incoming requests from all these other addresses.

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like the perils of asynchronous execution of code. You are defining the host and port and immediately calling them in the console log statement. NodeJS is executing the log statement before initializing. Try printing the log statement outside the app.listen function.

Comment: thanks I could be wrong but shouldnt it be the opposite? app.listen is trigger and only after it is done will the anonymous callback be called (which prints to the console, and by this point the server should be ready)